# Cannot add PTR record to VM instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm trying to add a public DNS PTR record to my google compute VM but it keeps saying:

> Editing VM instance "server" failed. Error: Invalid value for field 'resource.publicPtrDomainName': 'example.com'. Please verify ownership of the PTR domain at https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/verification?domain=example.com.

I have verified the domain and left the txt record for the verification on my dns configurations. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is an example where we need to know the DNS name you entered to help you.

Comment: Have you followed the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-ptr-record#domain_ownership) and verified your domain ownership?

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the user which verified the domain ownership and the user who is trying to add the PTR to the instance are the same.

You can check the user verification details at
https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification.

Run this command to check the user in google cloud console:

```
gcloud config get-value account
```

If both the users are same then try  the following steps:

Go to Google Webmaster Central--> Add property-->PTR domain name-->domain verification - "Alternate method"--> domain name provider (then copy the txt record it provides to your domain DNS zone records), once verified then,

Now, In google cloud console-->vm instance--> Edit instance--> nic0 --> public DNS PTR Record --> add your "domain.com" (exactly as shown in the verification result)

Make sure the domain name in Google Cloud "Public DNS PTR Record" should be the same as the host name.