# DNS validation for GCP PTR record

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to set up a pointer record for a static external IP address on Google cloud, and am stuck at the "verify domain ownership" step, which I'm trying to do via DNS. Trying to set the record in GCP > Compute Engine >  > Network Interfaces > Public DNS PTR Record results in

`Editing VM instance instance-20240222-135741 failed. Error: Invalid value for field 'resource.publicPtrDomainName': '<myhost>.<mydomain>.com'. Please verify ownership of the PTR domain. See more information at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-ptr-record#domain_ownership.`

Unfortunately, the linked doc [says](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-ptr-record#verify_by_adding_your_vms_ip_address_to_your_dns_configuration),

> Verify by adding your VM's IP address to your DNS configuration
>
> 1. If your VM does not exist yet, reserve a regional static external IP address and use it later during VM creation.
> 2. Add an "A" record with the VM's external IP address to the DNS configuration of your domain.

That point #2 is ... rather insufficient. I've tried adding an A record both for the host name I want to assign in the PTR with with IP address as the value, and (just guessing at possible solutions) tried it at the top level domain.

```
~ % dig <mydomain>.com
;; ANSWER SECTION:
<mydomain>.com. 600 IN  A   <the correct IP addr>
~ % nslookup <myhost>.<mydomain>.com
Server:     8.8.8.8     // it's even using Google's root servers!
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   <myhost>.<mydomain>.com
Address: <the correct IP addr>
```

What magic is Google wanting me to do in my DNS to "verify"?

Note, there are a few other questions on here about this verification step (e.g., [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/1058616/cannot-add-ptr-record-to-vm-instance)), but I can't find any attempting it with DNS; they're all doing it with the "Google Search Console" which ... I'd prefer not to do.

Comment: 1) 8.8.8.8 is not a root server. Notice the response `Non-authoritative answer`. 2) PTR records are configured in Compute Engine. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-ptr-record 3) Use the Google Search Console to verify domain ownership: https://search.google.com/search-console/welcome 4) You mention you prefer not to, but take my advice and make it easy for yourself. There are other methods that are more complicated or require more services.